# Compact abelian group and Continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, abelian-groups, locally-compact-groups

If $G$ is a compact abelian group, $\widehat{G}$ is the dual group of $G$,i.e. all the continuous homomorphism from $G$ to $S^1$,$S^1=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\big | |z|=1\}$.

Show that the linear span of $\widehat{G}$ is dense in $C(G)$,the continuous function space on $G$.

I try to solve this using stone-weierstrass theorem. But I need to prove that $\forall 0\neq g_0\in G$,there is $\gamma_0 \in \widehat{G}$ such that $\gamma_0(g_0)\neq 1$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a hard theorem.  Can you say more about what tools you are familiar with that you might be able to use?

Comment: @EricWofsey  i can use Stone-Weierstrass theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stone-WeierstrassTheorem.html

Comment: 1 $I \in \widehat{G}$; 2  if $\gamma \in \widehat{G}$,then conjugate of $\gamma$ is in $\widehat{G}$. thus I only need to prove that $\forall g_0\in G,g_0\neq 0$,then there exist $\gamma_0 \in \widehat{G}$,such that $\gamma_0(g_0)\neq 1$.